# Directory_map works only on C:

Tags: codeigniter

Directory_map works only on C: harddisk.
I want to use it on a server "P:" or "Q:" but that's not working currently.
I have full permission so I guess the problem is not about it.

```
$path = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\";

$map = directory_map(realpath($path), TRUE);
var_dump($map);
// WORKS
$path = "P:\INTRANET";
// DOESN'T WORKS
```

And the same things happend with get_filenames function ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, I found a pretty nice solution here :
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?27880-Using-function-opendir-on-a-network-drive #DaveRandom comment.

You can also see his contribution about that in php manual http://php.net//manual/fr/function.opendir.php

In fact, to use function (in codeigniter or php ) in a network drive, you had to map it.